# etags error xargs: etags: terminated by signal 7

Tags: emacs, xargs, etags

I used a command to have TAGS for emacs and i have lot of files in my project. After 20 seconds a get an error and my tags isn't generate i have this error when i create my tags. What is SIGEMT signal 7 ? How to avoid that ? Do you know an other solution to have tags on emacs?
Thanks a lot for your time.

my command :

```
find . -name "*.c" -print -or -name "*.cpp" -print -or -name "*.h" -print | xargs etags --append
```

my error :

```
   xargs: etags: terminated by signal 7
```

Comment: I have some directory to igniore and that's works.  I use -prune with my dir to igniore  find ./staging_dir/ -name "dirToIgniore*" -prune -or -name "*.h" -print | xargs etags --append && find ./dir/ -name "dirToIgniore*" -prune -name "*.c" -print -or -name "*.cpp" -print -or -name "*.h" -print | xargs etags --append

Answer (score 0):

I have some directory to igniore and that's works. I use -prune with my dir to igniore

```
find ./staging_dir/ -name "dirToIgniore*" -prune -or -name ".h" -print | xargs etags --append && find ./dir/ -name "dirToIgniore*" -prune -name ".c" -print -or -name ".cpp" -print -or -name "*.h" -print | xargs etags --append
```